# reload a UIwebview from main view automatically (view based application)

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a view based application. Now on the opening view I have some buttons and a picture and a small web view.

The web view has its own .h/.m file the calls a JSON request to fill it. That works great.

My problem is that when the app is closed and reopened the webview is not updating. How to I get that to work?

welcomeMessage.m (connected to webview)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{ 

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
NSUserDefaults *gMess =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myMess=[gMess stringForKey:@"welcomeMessage"];
NSLog(@"WEBVIEW CLASS %@",myMess);
if (myMess == NULL) {
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body style ='background-color:#FFFF33' align='center'><p>Welcome</p><p>Check out our Daily Winners</p></body>"];
    [welcomeMessage loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myapp.com/api/welcome/welcomemessage.php?iappid=37"]];
}
else{

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body style ='background-color:#FFFF33' align='center'> %@ </body>", myMess];
    [welcomeMessage loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myapp.com/api/welcome/welcomemessage.php?iappid=37"]];
}    
}
```

Mainviewcontroller json

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Create new SBJSON parser object

SBJsonParser *object = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kickintheapp.com/api/welcome/welcomemessage.php?iappid=37"]];
// NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSError *jsonParseError;
NSDictionary *status = [object objectWithString:json_string error:&jsonParseError];
if (!status) {
    // there's been a parse error; look at jsonParseError
    // for example:
    NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", jsonParseError);
}
NSString *messValue = [status objectForKey:@"message"];
NSUserDefaults *gMess = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[gMess setObject:messValue forKey:@"welcomeMessage"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Apple's documentation on an iOS's lifecycle. You will find all callbacks you need in there:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Especially `– applicationWillEnterForeground:` will be interesting for you.

Comment: Well I was using viewWillAppear and now I have tried applicationWillEnterForeground but still no luck on working.  I am putting it in my Main viewcontroller where my webview is and I am putting in the code from the viewdidLoad so It should load that right?

Comment: You will have to put that in your application's delegate to have it called. If you want to be notified in individual controllers, you'll have to subscribe to the corresponding notification, something like: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourCallback) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

Comment: ok I think I almost have it. so I put my awakeFromNib code from my welcomeMessage.m file in my applicationWillEnter.. but it says unknown reciever on the welcomeMessage or If I change it to WelcomeMessage it says loadHTMLstring not found. on the [welcomeMessage loadHTMLString:...] line.    Is there a way in my app delicate to just call the awakefromNib method in my WelcomeMessage.m class?

Comment: The welcomeMessage member/property belongs to the view, not to the app delegate, that's why it is unknown. You don't have a view controller, do you? If not: make a method in your view, let's say "-loadMessage:". In that, put your code from the awakeFromNib. In your app delegate you should have a reference to your view somewhere. Send that view [yourView loadMessage].

Comment: You asked if I have a viewcontroller.  Yes I do. Several. my .h .m and on my myAppViewController.xib.  That layout looks like this: View Controller(linked to Welcome Message class); inside that : View. Inside that: UiWebview and some buttons.  now i can get a log message to appear when using applicationWillEnterForeground in the appDelegate. but nothing when I put code in there.   Thank you for all help btw.  I'm kinda lost at this point